# Van der Waerden function is in $\mathrm{Lip}_\alpha$ for $\alpha<1$

Tags: real-analysis

This is a starred exercise from Stephen Krantz's Real Analysis and Foundations (Section 6 in the third edition) and I'm quite stuck on it.

First define $\psi(x)$:

$$
\psi(x) = \left\{\begin{array}[lll]
xx-n & \text{if} & n \leq x < n+1 \text{ and $n$ is even} \\
n+1-x & \text{if} & n \leq x < n+1 \text{ and $n$ is odd} 
\end{array}\right.
$$

Now define van der Waerden's nowhere differentiable function:

$$
f(x) = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^j\psi(4^jx)
$$

The exercise is to prove $f(x)$ is in $\mathrm{Lip}_\alpha$ for all $\alpha<1$, ie

$$
|f(s)-f(t)| \leq C |s-t|^\alpha \label{lipschitz}
$$
for some suitable constant $C$.

Useful things to note:

1. $|\psi(s)-\psi(t)| \leq |s-t|$
2. $|\psi(s)-\psi(t)| \leq 1$

Together they lead to

$$
\begin{equation}\label{inequality}
|f(s)-f(t)| \leq \sum_{j=1}^N 3^j |s-t| + \sum_{j=N+1}^{\infty} (\frac{3}{4})^j 
\end{equation}
$$

The secord term means I can't use this to prove uniform continuity (which is supposed to fail anyway), but I was hoping that the weaker Lipschitz condition may be compatible with this. Obviously this is still too weak: for $|s-t|$ sufficiently small the inequality above does not lead to the Lipschitz condition. And it's clear that for $|s-t|$ sufficiently large the Lipschitz condition is automatically satisfied. So I think I only need a tip on what to do in the small $|s-t|$ case.

Thanks in advance!